# Trying to connect to my sql database getting exception saying "no suitable driver found"

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm using the tutorial at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html
to try tp connect to my sql server on my server

When it executes the line:

```
Connection connect = DriverManager
              .getConnection("jdbc:mysql:http://www.findmeontheweb.biz"
                  + "user=findmeon_bitcoin&password=PASSWORD");
```

an exception gets thrown saying "`No sutabled driver found for    jdbc:mysql:http://www.findmeontheweb.biz`

This is what I did
1. Downloaded the "mysql-connecter-java-5.1.33.bin.jar into my lib folder
2. added the jar to my project from preferences.

project code:

```
public class cStart {

      private Connection connect = null;
      private Statement statement = null;
      private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
      private ResultSet resultSet = null;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int g=0;
          try {

              // this will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
              // setup the connection with the DB.

              // EXCEPTION GOES OF HEAR
              Connection connect = DriverManager
                  .getConnection("jdbc:mysql:http://www.findmeontheweb.biz"
                      + "user=findmeon_bitcoin&password=PASSWORD");


     } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Exception...." );
        } 

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL format should be look like this

**jdbc:mysql://hostname/ databaseName**

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a much cleaner way to do it:

```
String URL = "jdbc:URL_TO_YOUR_DATBASE";
String USER = "username";
String PASS = "password"
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
```

As seen here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-db-connections.htm

I say give that link a try with your driver. You also should make sure you have the actual jar for MySQL. It really might be invalid.

I would try the one here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommysqljdbc515jar.htm

And then add that to your project.

Answer (score 0):

The URL to the database might be wrong.

If yes you should specify a correct one with including database name.

Else verify if the `jdbc driver jar` is added in the `build-path`, if yes try to put it in the `lib` folder of your `webapp`.